# How to interpret zero P value

Tags: p-value

I am doing a research on factors affecting job satisfaction, I got the following result with a zero p value.

Hypothesis test,

```
H1: There is a positive relationship between Working Conditions and Job satisfaction 

H0: There is **no positive** relationship between Working Conditions and Job satisfaction
```

Results (Minitab),
Correlation: Job Satisfaction, Work Conditions

> Pearson correlation of Job Satisfaction and Work Conditions = 0.492
>
> P-Value = 0.000

My interpretation is:
"There is a significant positive relationship between job satisfaction and working conditions"

Is this correct?

Comment: If there is no evidence for something, we do not accept that it is true. You seem to confuse "null hypothesis" with "alternative hypothesis". Also in your example H0 is "there is a relation" while null hypothesis is about no relation (r=0).

Comment: Tim, just to clarify this, Ho is null hypothesis and H1 is alternative hypothesis? Please correct me if I am wrong, I am new to this.

Comment: Yes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have corrected the Ho and H1. Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Note that P = 0.000 just means "zero to 3 decimal places". Good software will show you more decimal places on request; at the same time, you don't need them here, or mostly elsewhere. Yes, you have a significant correlation, but that's only a very little deal. The bigger questions are: how are "working conditions" and "job satisfaction" measured variables? Does correlation really make sense here?

Comment: Incidentally: The true *p*-value isn't really zero, but it rounds to 0.000 to 3 decimal places. It is quite common to see this reported as *p* < 0.001. It does indeed suggest you have strong evidence of a positive correlation.

Comment: And see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90490)

Comment: Being rather fussy I would replace the word relationship in the question with correlation, To me relationship implies some causation and correlation may not.